# jQuery - How to know which parameter(s) is/are optional in the callback function when reading the documentation

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery documentation, I have no idea on how to acknowledge which callback function parameters are optional. Take the `getJSON()` function for example. We know that if the parameter is optional, it is enclosed within square brackets `[]`, but for the callback function, there is no indication telling us which of the parameters are optional.

Here is the link to `getJSON()` function: [getJSON documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Take a look at a parameter called `success`. It is a callback function and it has 3 parameters (PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR) but some of them are optional. So, how do we know which of the 3 parameters are optional?

Comment: All params in callback are optional.

Comment: @blackmiaool Haha... really? thanks. I think you should answer the question so that I can select it as accepted answer.

Comment: It's ok. Short answers are usually in comment area on this site.

Comment: @blackmiaool I was just thinking. What if the arguments are of the same type. For example, all of them are string. How can the browser know which one we are passing?

Comment: Generally libs check the length of arguments to ensure what argument you are passing. Try to read some source code, it's good for you.

Comment: By the way, the conclusion in the first comment is just true for jQuery. There are some libs may request you to name the arguments specifically.

Comment: @blackmiaool Those are the exception however, and it's a bad practice. In those cases, it will be documented extensively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a callback you only need to specify what params that you need to use really. None are actually "required".

```
$.each(array,function(k){ console.log(k); });
```

Is functionally the same as:

```
$.each(array,function(k,v){ console.log(k); });
```

Assuming that you don't need to use the value somewhere in the callback.

Now... that being said.

```
$.each(array,function(v){ console.log(v); });
```

Is not the same as:

```
$.each(array,function(k,v){ console.log(v); });
```

This means that you DO have to specify all the parameters that extend out to the parameter your trying to use.

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thank you for the enlightenment. So, the jQuery developers arranged the parameters from most important to least important when they declare the callback function, right?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation just tells you with which arguments it will call your callback (when you supply one). It will always pass all of them - it doesn't care how many you actually use. This is fine given the [variadic nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) of JS functions - too many arguments will be ignored, too few will be filled up with `undefined`.

You, on the other hand, are totally free to choose which ones to use and to declare. When you don't need a parameter, omit it.